# UIPopoverController? Cannot dismissed when tapping outside the popover controller

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, uipopovercontroller

I have a problem that began after I changed my project to a universal application and switched to the updated version of Xcode.

At the moment, my application has a navigation bar with a controller that has a button. The button will pop up a UIPopoverController when the user clicks it. Everything was fine here. Now I try to interact with the list inside UIPopoverController and there is no reaction at all in the list. In addition, when I try to dismiss the popover controller by tapping outside the popover controller, the popup does dismiss at all as well as I can even interact the controls behind the popover controller.

It worked fine before I updated Xcode to the latest IOS. Inside the code I have changed was having the xib file to have the window view and inside the app delegate file I initialized that xib file.

This is shown the code below.

```
TViewController* controller = [[TController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MainViewController_IPad" bundle:NULL];
[controller.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:TRUE animated:TRUE];
self.window = [[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]] autorelease];
[self.window setRootViewController:controller];
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

//((TopicShowViewController*)self.window.rootViewController).navigationController.navigationBarHidden = true;
self.navigationController = ((TopicShowViewController*)self.window.rootViewController).navigationController;
self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = true;
[controller release];
```

The code above, I have to create the window object but the TViewController itself has a window object already. If i run this without either window object in the xib file or explicit initialized the window object from code above, the TViewController won't display as expected.

I have no idea what is going wrong here... Sorry the description may be too long to understand but please help.

Answer (score 1):

A *universal application* is an app designed to run on both an iPhone and an iPad. However, the UIPopoverController is not supported on the iPhone.  If you try open a popover on an iPhone your app will throw an exception.

Comment: Sorry. I have two project where one is for iPhone and other for iPad. I wanted to merge them together. In the universal Application, iPhone will have it's own code and iPad has own code but may shared similar code too. The problem i am facing here is target the iPad one not the iPhone.